# aws data migration service . start replication task issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-dms

I have created AWS DMS replication instance, replication task and source, target enpoints using terrform.

Now, when i run start replication task from windows aws cli . it throws this SSL error.

Error running command 'aws dms start-replication-task --start-replication-task-type start-replication --replication-task-arn arn:aws:dms:us-west-2:accountnumber:task:xxxxxxx': exit status 254. Output: C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1020: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'dms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.
My CLI version is The version is aws-cli/2.1.6 Python/3.7.9 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off.

There is no proxy configured

Any suggestion on this issue.

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your credential correctly where you replication task is living by set `[default]`  on the right one

```
./aws/credentials
```

to start the replication task you have to fill two mandatory field

```
{
  "ReplicationTaskArn": "string",
   "StartReplicationTaskType": "string"
}
```

**StartReplicationTaskType** --> Valid Values: start-replication | resume-processing | reload-target

start-replication only when you create the task so you may need to make it `reload-target`

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/APIReference/API_StartReplicationTask.html